# How to calculate total resistance and identify which resistors are in series?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel, series, ohms-law

How to calculate the total resistance and identify which resistors are in series?

[image]

I'm really lost with this one. How do I properly read this?

Comment: Can you identify any two resistors in series?

Comment: 1k and 3k or 3k and 2.2k 

Comment: Resistors in series must have the same current through them. The current through the 1K encounters a node before the 3k. So which pair is in series?

Comment: So its 3k and 2.2 which need to sum and count with another parallel then sum it with 1k. Im not sure but i think 2.4k is the correct answer..

Comment: You got it! It is just that easy.

Comment: Thank you man

Comment: One way to know whether two resistors are in parallel is if they share two nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 kΩ and 2.2 kΩ resistors are in series; they have the same current going through them.

The 1 kΩ and 3 kΩ resistors don't; they have a node between them and some of the current "branches off", so they are not in series.

It may make it easier to see if you redraw the schematic without changing the nodes and branches:

[image]

So you have 1 kΩ in series with 2 kΩ || 5.2 kΩ.